# Make pagination component and dropdown aligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a website with twitter bootstrap and making a table with pagination i got certain problem. basicly i can't make the pagination and dropdown button aligned in-line.

Using @flackend's JSFiddle to show the problem: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gVg7H/1/)
**code**

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> Usuarios <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a id="enaUsr" href="#"><i class="icon-ok-circle"></i> Activar Cuenta(s)</a></li>
                    <li><a id="enaUsr" href="#"><i class="icon-remove-circle"></i> Desactivar Cuenta(s)</a></li><li><a href="#"><i id="delUsr" class="icon-trash"></i> Eliminar</a></li>    </ul>

</div>
<div class="pagination pagination-right">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Prev</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
</div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

Any Ideas ???

Comment: use `float: left;` on your button else can you post your CSS
 out here

Comment: the css is the twitter's bootstrap.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want them on the same line? CSS float left:

http://jsfiddle.net/flackend/gVg7H/

Comment: nop no success i posted the code updated using your JsFiddle in the question :D

Comment: How do you want it to look? I assume on the same "line" with the drop-down aligned left and the pagination aligned right. That's how it is now. The pagination has a top and bottom margin of `18px` which makes it look like their not.

Comment: yes i want to make it visible in the same line, hmmmm i will make the floated button style with a similar margin